# animation player ( playing movies that are swf files )

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Hi i am looking for a flash/flex component that plays movies that are not .flv but .swf with controllers such as fast forward, stop, play and a timeline.
I have a flv player which does the same but some movies I don't want to play bitmap movies but vector for quality reasons ( as movieclips )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using SWFLoader

Answer (score 0):

You can even try dragging these swf files into a web browser. They will play in the browser, if you right click on the movie that is loaded, you will get option to play, pause and arrow clicks will give you the ability like fastforward etc.

Hope this helps.